# Get style at caret position in a JTextPane

Tags: java, styling, caret, jtextpane

I have a basic text editor that can style documents (bold, underline, italicize, underline, align left/right/center, color, font size/family), and that all works great. The problem I'm having is that I want the style to set my buttons and boxes to the correct styling for where the caret is.

Say, for example, I have the string

> *the quick brown fox* **jumps over the lazy dog**

When I click between the u and i in quick, I want my italicize button to be toggled on to indicate that the text where the caret is has the italicized styling.

I'm using a JTextPane to hold the text, and a StyledEditorKit for the styling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for, is

`getCharacterAttributes` method from the JTextPane

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#getCharacterAttributes()

Comment: After some tinkering, this turned out to be what I was looking for, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just for anyone still looking for and didnt find the answer :
for example :

```
AttributeSet attributeSet = textPane.getCharacterAttributes();
Object bold = attributeSet == null ? null : attributeSet.getAttribute( StyleConstants.Bold );
System.out.println( "Bold : " + bold );
```